# other option at place of <bool> tag

Tags: ant

```
<if>
   <bool>
      <isgreaterthan arg1="${abc}" arg2="${xyz}"/>
   </bool>
</if>
```

when i am running the code, it's showing the error  `if doesn't support the nested "bool" element.`
is there any other option is there at the place of bool which supported by if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ant Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) is a new Ant Plugin that provides an innovative Expression Language which makes many scripting part obsolete. Beside that Flaka provides conditional and repetitive control structures like when, unless, while, for, choose, switch ..
Your if statement with Flaka would look like =

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">

  <property name="digitA" value="42"/>
  <property name="digitB" value="23"/>
  <property name="wordA"  value="abcd"/>
  <property name="wordB"  value="efgh"/>

  <!-- compare of digits -->
  <fl:when test=" '${digitA}' > '${digitB}' ">
    <echo>${digitA} gt ${digitB}</echo>
  </fl:when>

  <!-- example with string compare in switch -->
  <fl:switch value="${wordA}">
    <cmp gt="${wordB}">
      <echo>${wordA} gt ${wordB}</echo>
    </cmp>
    <cmp lt="${wordB}">
    <echo>${wordA} lt ${wordB}</echo>
    </cmp>
  </fl:switch>

</project>
```

please see the comprehensive [Flaka Manual](http://flaka.googlecode.com/files/flaka.pdf) for further details !

Comment: HI! r u there? i want to use input property within switch case for taking run time two integer input for comparing them and printing greater one.but it's showing the Error `ns:switch doesn't support the nested "input" element.`

Comment: That's right, means you can't do <ns:switch><input ...></ns:switch>. See Flaka manual (http://flaka.googlecode.com/files/flaka.pdf) page 38 for all valid elements that may be used directly after <ns:switch>. But after the first nesting other tasks like input are allowed. F.e. <ns:switch ..><cmp eq="..."><input ..>...</cmp>. Please provide further details, try to put it in pseudocode

Answer (score 5):

The example works in antcontrib-1.0b2 but not the latest antcontrib-1.0b3

Found this after hitting a similar problem after an update

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're attempting to use the [Antelope `if` task](http://antelope.tigris.org/nonav/docs/manual/bk03ch05.html), as it (unlike the [ant-contrib `if`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html)) supports a nested `bool` element.  But, the error message is indicative of the task not being defined correctly.

Check that you have the Antelope jar, and a suitable taskdef in your buildfile.  I use this:

```
<taskdef resource="ise/antelope/tasks/antlib.xml"
         classpath="path/to/AntelopeTasks_3.5.1.jar" />
```

For details of what the task supports, see the documentation linked to above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'bool' tag within 'if' provided you use taskdef for "if" using the classname="ise.antelope.tasks.IfTask"

Eg:

```
<target name="compare">  <taskdef name="if" classname="ise.antelope.tasks.IfTask"/>  <var name="abc" value="2" />  <var name="xyz" value="1" />  <if>  <bool>  <isgreaterthan arg1="${abc}" arg2="${xyz}"/>  </bool>  <echo message="${abc} is greater than ${xyz}" />  </if>  </target>
```