# Apache Ant Less Than

Tags: ant

How on earth do you check a number property is less than in Apache Ant?

```
<property name="small" value="15"/>
<property name="big" value="156"/>
<fail message="small is less than big!">
  <condition>
    <lessthan val1="${small}" val2="${big}"/>
  </condition>
</fail>
```

From what I've seen (I'm new to Ant) you can only do `<equal/>`?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639902/apache-ant-comparing-properties-variables which sadly makes it seem like you'll have to embed some script.

Comment: Thanks ccoakley. Pity I put less than in the header rather than greater than as the Stackoverflow search didn't pick it up :(.  Voted to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `<scriptcondition>` (see http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html).

Read the documentation carefully because it would need installing additional jar dependencies in ant.

The condition could look like that (not tested):

```
<scriptcondition language="javascript">
    var small = parseInt(project.getProperty("small"));
    var big = parseInt(project.getProperty("big"));

    self.setValue(small < big);
</scriptcondition>
```

Comment: I liked the look of the `isgreaterthan` task in Ant-Contrib (already using that), I can't work out how to use it though.

Comment: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/more_conditions.html did u try this?

Comment: @MattClarkson Are you maybe trying to use `<isgreaterthan>` in a `<condition>` task?  From the link that @FailedDev provided: "Unfortunately, they cannot be used in the <condition> task".

Comment: I get  The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup. on the < sign

Answer (score 3):

Here is the usage of `<isgreaterthan>` condition task with out any scripting:

```
<if>
    <isgreaterthan arg1="100" arg2="10"/>
    <then>
        <echo>Number 100 is greater than number 10</echo>
    </then>
</if>
```

Also, arg1, arg2 value can be of property variable.

Note: `<isgreaterthan>` is an additional condition available with Ant-Contrib:

http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/more_conditions.html

Comment: Sure this works? From the docs: "These conditions are suitable for use in the <bool> element. Unfortunately, they cannot be used in the <condition> task...". When I try this, the build fails: "if doesn't support the nested "isgreaterthan" element"

Answer (score 2):

Cheers JB Nizet, finally got there.

```
<!-- Test the Ant Version -->
<property name="burning-boots-web-build.required-ant-version" value="1.8.2"/>
<script language="javascript">
    <![CDATA[
        var current     = project.getProperty("ant.version").match(/([0-9](\.)?)+/)[0].replace(/\./g,"");
        var required    = project.getProperty("burning-boots-web-build.required-ant-version").match(/([0-9](\.)?)+/)[0].replace(/\./g,"");
        project.setProperty('ant.valid-version', current < required ? "false" : "true");
    ]]>
</script>
<fail message="This build requires Ant version ${burning-boots-web-build.required-ant-version}.">
    <condition>
        <isfalse value="${ant.valid-version}"/>
    </condition>
</fail>
```

Answer (score 0):

A "less than" comparioson of *properties* is not possible without either custom tasks or an embedded script.

But in most cases you can get away by applying the test not to the property but to the source of the values. In in a build system these "sources" are usually files. On files you can use the `isfileselected` [condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) together with a [selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html). Most selectors accept `when` attributes like `less`, `more` or `equal`.

The manual for the `isfileselected` condition show an example.

Answer (score 0):

The Ant addon [**Flaka**](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) provides a fail task that evaluates EL expressions, f.e. :

```
<project name="demo" xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
 <property name="small" value="15"/>
 <property name="big" value="156"/>
 <fl:fail message="small is less than big!" test="small lt big"/>
</project>
```

output :

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/rosebud/workspace/Ant/demo.xml:7: small is less than big!
```

see [**Flaka manual**](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/wiki/Manual) for further details

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer provided by @GnanaPrakash is incomplete.
From the [Ant Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/more_conditions.html) documentation:

> These conditions are suitable for use in the  element. Unfortunately, they cannot be used in the <condition> task, although all conditions for the  task can be used with the <bool> and the <bool> can be used anywhere that <condition> can be used.

So, the `islessthan` or the alternative `isgreaterthan` elements **must** be wrapped in a `bool` element like so:

```
<property name="small" value="15" />
<property name="big" value="156" />
<if>
    <bool>
        <islessthan arg1="${small}" arg2="${big}"/>
    </bool>
    <then>
        <echo message="small is less than big!" />
    </then>
    <else>
        <echo message="big is less than small!" />
    </else>
</if>
```

If you don't do it this way you'll get an error saying:

```
if doesn't support the nested "islessthan" element.
```

Comment: Small note: apparently this doesn't work with antcontrib-1.0b3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12391161/2581587